# Terminate JavaFX Application using Platform.exit()

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFX 2.2 and I have a class which extends `Application`. Here is my code:

```
Class A extends Application { 
    public void Stage(final Stage primaryStage) { ... }
    public void Start(){ 
        launch(); 
    } 
    btnLogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
        Platform.exit(); 
    } 
} 

Class B{ } 

Class C extends Application{ 
    public void Stage(final Stage primaryStage) { ... } 
    public void Start(){ 
        launch(); 
    } 
}
```

Actually, Class `A` is login screen; it will close when I successfully log in. Then the screen closed by `platform.exit()` function. After that I execute view button in Class `B` , Class `C` called but there are some problems.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
```

I just terminate the screen by using `Platform.exit()` function but I can't understand why it can't be closed.

Comment: Are you using `Platform.exit()` just to hide your `Stage` ? How are you making a call to `Class C`. Why do you have to use two `Application` ?

Comment: Because it have different function. Class A application is Login Screen, Class C application is WebView using WebEngine.
so i use two Application. but there are some error. they can't use 1 more..
thanks!

Comment: Is it a Swing Application ? Are you trying to [Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) ?

Comment: I'll add more information.. give me a second..

Comment: Umm..i just use Java Swing in Class B. because it is Main screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Class B` is the main screen and you need to `Embed JavaFX` in your application for Login Screen or any other screen, you don't need `Class A` and `Class C` to extend `Application`.

You can just create a new Window in Swing inside these classes (A and C) and use [`JFXPanel` to embed JavaFX into your Swing Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm). This way you can have full control on the application and you can easily open and close windows for `Login` or any other functionality that you want.

**N.B.** *You should not have two class extending `Application` inside one app, as only one JavaFX thread is allowed per JVM*.

Everytime you try to do this you will get this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once

Answer (score 1):

Platform.exit() actually terminates whole jfx.
To keep things safe, just invoke launch() once and show/hide new windows.

Something like:

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);//make fx running in backgound.
Platform.runLater/AndWait {//make sure u create window in jfx thread
//window creation/show code here.
}
```

Comment: i want to close Login Application. and open Class B. Class B is Main Frame using java swing. and then i want to open webview in class B. so i use Platform.exit()..